# Flex 3 static bitmap issue

Tags: caching, flex3, bitmapdata

Interesting problem here - I'm making a small game using Flex 3 - now I have a static ImageAccess class, which first loads up all images and stores them in a static array for quicker access in the future.

Now since I address the physical bitmapdata without calling Clone() (for efficiency issues) and once by accident I've written directly onto the bitmapdata.

Now the weird part - Flex uses some kind of weird caching and stores the bitmap with the new changes made to it - no matter what I do (restart Flex Builder, delete my cache, restart browser) the bitmap data is still loaded with the extra info (even though the image is without all that data).

Please help :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details about what extra info you're talking about? 
Correct me if I'm wrong but Flex doesn't cache anything as such, the browser does,  in any case , viewing with another browser should display the original image. If it doesn't , you may consider the possibility of some forgotten function still acting on the original bitmap... have you tried viewing the application in another browser by the way? 
there's also the possibility of the original image being corrupted for whatever reason...